# Google Cloud : How to send data within the network using public hostname without incurring the data transfer cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, google-cloud-platform

I've a log aggregator service running on a cluster in Google Cloud. Applications both from inside and outside the Google cloud platform are supposed to send data to this service. Due to the design, there is a constraint that all internal/external apps can use only the same hostname/ip to communicate with the service.

Now, if I use external IP as the advertised hostname, the system works fine but I'll be charged by Google for sending the data from Apps in internal network to the service. I want to avoid incurring this cost.

On the other hand, AWS provides a public hostname which resolves to public ip from outside the network but resolves to internal ip from inside the network. This way I could have used public hostname for the service without incurring cost for internal data transfer. Is there a way to achieve the same thing in Google cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS EC2 does make this easy by providing hostnames that automatically resolve to either the public or private IPs depending on where they're being accessed. Google Cloud doesn't currently have this feature but here are some ways around it:

- Use the hostnames of the instances, instead of the IPs. The hostname will automatically be resolved to the internal IP when used inside GCP. When outside, you can edit the local hosts file on the external machines to resolve to the external IP. This isn't easy to scale though if you have lots of external machines or if they're outside your control.
- Run your own DNS server, setup a new domain, and automatically respond with the right IP depending on where the request is coming from.
- Use a virtual SDN (software defined network) to automatically route traffic. All the hosts will be on the same virtual LAN network and you can use internal IPs between them all. Internal hosts will automatically connect directly and external hosts will use a tunnel over the public internet, but both will use the same IPs. [ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com/) or [Pritunl](https://pritunl.com/) are good choices depending on what you need.

Comment: thanks Mani, just came across your answer. I also thought of the first two approaches, and ended up doing the first one as it was the simplest and scale was limited.